# How to prevent script tags and other XSS entities from being inserted into the db?

Tags: coldfusion, xss, coldfusion-10

I have a form which contains many text boxes. All the text boxes are required fields. As these are textboxes I can not use specific
validation except the length. But i do not want to allow the users to insert  tags that are vulnerable to xss attacks.

I know in ColdFusion i can use htmlEditFormat(),encodeForHTML() while displaying user data for preventing XSS, But I just want to
prevent those from inserting to db.'GlobalScriptProtect' option also does not add much security as per my knowledge. As I am in CF10, so can not use getSafeHTML()

Is there any way to prevent theses malicious inputs from inserting into the DB in CF10. Can I go for client side sensitization ?

Answer (score 5):

There is a UDF on CFlib.org [isXss](http://www.cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=2116) that checks a value to determine if it is xss.  I have used this function and built a custom tag to check every form field and query string field before I submit it to the database.  After implementing this, I have been able to pass countless PCI scans and have not had any xss issues.